# SQL Server: arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query executing in client side

```
select * 
from orders 
where orderid > @id and orderid < @id + 1000
```

Now the `@id` value is 2147483647 and I'm getting this error:

[image: com.microsoft.]

I tried to cast and convert like below

```
select * 
from orders 
where orderid > @id and orderid < cast(@id + 1000 as bigint)
```

but no luck.

Is there a way to cast/convert the addition into `bigint` in the `where` condition?

Thanks

Comment: Column orderid data type?

Comment: Apparently you need to change the data type of the variable `@id` to `bigint`. But I think that you also can do like this `cast(@id as bigint) + 1000`

Comment: bigint. orderid has 2148504713 in orders table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast before adding:

```
select *
from orders
where orderid > @id and orderid < cast(@id as bigint) + 1000 ;
```

Or better yet, declare `@id` to be a `bigint`.